# Android: How can I make text views float to the left?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to make textviews float to the left (like css floats). The reason I have so many textviews is I want every word in my app to be clickable. So I want this result:
[image]

Currently, I have the following xml codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:baselineAligned="false">
    <TextView android:text="@string/nicholasStr" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nicholas" ></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="@string/wasStr" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/was" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/dots" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/dots"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/older" android:id="@+id/older"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/older" android:id="@+id/older"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/older" android:id="@+id/older"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="@string/older" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/older"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the result goes like this:

[image]

I'm new to android dev, many thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Try using `android:orientation = "vertical"`.

Comment: Try with `RelativeLayout` and also check this article [link] http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

Comment: if you make them dynamically in java rather than with xml. You could just check the right edge of the last one to see how far from the edge of the screen it is so so know when you need to jump to the next row.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. @Tim: do you have a sample code for that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you really need is a row layout that wraps entire views.  Unfortunately Android doesn't have one.  Lucky for you though, I do! ;)

It is a custom class, but you can use it in xml just fine as long as you fully qualify it, and include the following attrs.xml file under res/values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RowLayout">
        <attr name="android:verticalSpacing" />
        <attr name="android:horizontalSpacing" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Here is the source:

```
package com.example.widget;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.widget.R;

public class RowLayout extends ViewGroup {
    public static final int DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_SPACING = 5;
    public static final int DEFAULT_VERTICAL_SPACING = 5;
    private final int horizontalSpacing;
    private final int verticalSpacing;
    private List<RowMeasurement> currentRows = Collections.emptyList();

    public RowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RowLayout);
        horizontalSpacing = styledAttributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RowLayout_android_horizontalSpacing,
                DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_SPACING);
        verticalSpacing = styledAttributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RowLayout_android_verticalSpacing,
                DEFAULT_VERTICAL_SPACING);
        styledAttributes.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int maxInternalWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - getHorizontalPadding();
        final int maxInternalHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - getVerticalPadding();
        List<RowMeasurement> rows = new ArrayList<RowMeasurement>();
        RowMeasurement currentRow = new RowMeasurement(maxInternalWidth, widthMode);
        rows.add(currentRow);
        for (View child : getLayoutChildren()) {
            LayoutParams childLayoutParams = child.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = createChildMeasureSpec(childLayoutParams.width, maxInternalWidth, widthMode);
            int childHeightSpec = createChildMeasureSpec(childLayoutParams.height, maxInternalHeight, heightMode);
            child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (currentRow.wouldExceedMax(childWidth)) {
                currentRow = new RowMeasurement(maxInternalWidth, widthMode);
                rows.add(currentRow);
            }
            currentRow.addChildDimensions(childWidth, childHeight);
        }

        int longestRowWidth = 0;
        int totalRowHeight = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < rows.size(); index++) {
            RowMeasurement row = rows.get(index);
            totalRowHeight += row.getHeight();
            if (index < rows.size() - 1) {
                totalRowHeight += verticalSpacing;
            }
            longestRowWidth = Math.max(longestRowWidth, row.getWidth());
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ? MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) : longestRowWidth
                + getHorizontalPadding(), heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ? MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
                : totalRowHeight + getVerticalPadding());
        currentRows = Collections.unmodifiableList(rows);
    }

    private int createChildMeasureSpec(int childLayoutParam, int max, int parentMode) {
        int spec;
        if (childLayoutParam == LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT) {
            spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(max, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        } else if (childLayoutParam == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
            spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(max, parentMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ? MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
                    : MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        } else {
            spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childLayoutParam, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        return spec;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int leftPosition, int topPosition, int rightPosition, int bottomPosition) {
        final int widthOffset = getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingRight();
        int x = getPaddingLeft();
        int y = getPaddingTop();

        Iterator<RowMeasurement> rowIterator = currentRows.iterator();
        RowMeasurement currentRow = rowIterator.next();
        for (View child : getLayoutChildren()) {
            final int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            final int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (x + childWidth > widthOffset) {
                x = getPaddingLeft();
                y += currentRow.height + verticalSpacing;
                if (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    currentRow = rowIterator.next();
                }
            }
            child.layout(x, y, x + childWidth, y + childHeight);
            x += childWidth + horizontalSpacing;
        }
    }

    private List<View> getLayoutChildren() {
        List<View> children = new ArrayList<View>();
        for (int index = 0; index < getChildCount(); index++) {
            View child = getChildAt(index);
            if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                children.add(child);
            }
        }
        return children;
    }

    protected int getVerticalPadding() {
        return getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
    }

    protected int getHorizontalPadding() {
        return getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    }

    private final class RowMeasurement {
        private final int maxWidth;
        private final int widthMode;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public RowMeasurement(int maxWidth, int widthMode) {
            this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
            this.widthMode = widthMode;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public boolean wouldExceedMax(int childWidth) {
            return widthMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ? false : getNewWidth(childWidth) > maxWidth;
        }

        public void addChildDimensions(int childWidth, int childHeight) {
            width = getNewWidth(childWidth);
            height = Math.max(height, childHeight);
        }

        private int getNewWidth(int childWidth) {
            return width == 0 ? childWidth : width + horizontalSpacing + childWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to let some newbie like me know that they need the following line:

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
in the root layout. i.e.

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

Comment: Great answer. Works like a charm. It will be awesome if you can put it up on Github, maybe with a small documentation. Let me know if I can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with Relative layout with orientation = vertical.

for example: on **activity_main.xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnButton1"/>

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/btnButton3"
     android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
     android:text="User :"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
  .......

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty simple solution to create a menu with rows of options:

```
public class OptionMenu extends LinearLayout {
private int widthConsumed = 0;
private LinearLayout currentRow;

interface OptionRunnable {
    void onOptionSelected(int option);
}

public OptionMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
}

public void setOptions(List<Integer> options, OptionRunnable runnable) {
    getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

            Stream.of(options).forEach(option -> {
                TextView text = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.incl_textviewer_option_button, OptionMenu.this, false);
                text.setText(option);
                text.setTag(option);
                text.setOnClickListener(v -> runnable.onOptionSelected((Integer) v.getTag()));

                text.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                getCurrentRow(text.getMeasuredWidth()).addView(text);
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private LinearLayout getCurrentRow(int width) {
    if(currentRow == null) {
        currentRow = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        currentRow.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        addView(currentRow);
    }

    widthConsumed += width;

    if(widthConsumed < getWidth())
        return currentRow;

    LinearLayout newRow = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    newRow.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    currentRow = newRow;
    widthConsumed = width;
    addView(newRow);

    return newRow;
}
}
```